# joomla 2.5 navigation menu subtitle

Tags: php, joomla, menu, navigation, joomla2.5

Hi I am web designer and I would like to know how to set menu subtitle? It is easily possible with yoo themes but I need to know how it is done without using YooTheme templates. I think there is need of little modification in mod_menu but I don't know what exactly. I googled all day and can't find a solution.

Comment: what do you mean by subtitle? where?

Comment: Maybe attach an image to that we understand what you mean.

Comment: subtitle like this template has http://demo.rockettheme.com/?template=kirigami and no image would be bad idea because of SEO and increasing number of file calls

Comment: You mean **Welcome!** that's under **Home** and **Awesome Stuff** under **Features** etc... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly better solutions but i've done it this way:

Insert a charakter in the name of your menu-item. For example a "|".
It should look like this: Title | Subtitle. At this position you can divide the name.

Now you have to [override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) the file default_component.php in modules/mod_menu/tmpl.

Add this lines:

```
$parts = explode("|", $linktype);
// the "|" is the divider
if(isset($parts[1])){
    $linktype = $parts[0].'<span>'.$parts[1].'</span>';
}else{
    $linktype = $parts[0];
};
```

after:

```
$class = $item->anchor_css ? 'class="'.$item->anchor_css.'" ' : '';
$title = $item->anchor_title ? 'title="'.$item->anchor_title.'" ' : '';
if ($item->menu_image) {
        $item->params->get('menu_text', 1 ) ?
        $linktype = '<img src="'.$item->menu_image.'" alt="'.$item->title.'" /><span class="image-title">'.$item->title.'</span> ' :
        $linktype = '<img src="'.$item->menu_image.'" alt="'.$item->title.'" />';
}
else { $linktype = $item->title;
}
```

Now you have a span around the subtitle and it's possible to style it.